# Looping through row QTableWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to make use of a QTableWidget in my program.  When button is pressed, it should read the values of each column on first row of the QTableWidget and assign it to a variable to be used later.

[image]

Right now, it currently prints out correctly, but it then gives me an attribute error and freezes program.

Code:

```
def Loopthru(self):
    for i in range(0, 5):
        t = self.valveThicknessTable.item(0,i).text()### Returns error :AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
    print(t) ###test
```

I assume it has something to do with trying to loop through the columns with variable i. Any ideas why it is giving me this error?

Test program code:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzcHlfStubD3R0VBTWZDQXp1bWc?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The range was wrong, it was trying to put a blank cell into a variable.